# Grover search with single query to $f(x)$ and multiple queries to $f(x) = a$

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

Assume $f(x)$ is an $n$ bits to $m$ bits function and we want to use Grover's search algorithm to find $x$ such that $f(x) = a$, where $a$ is some $m$-bit predetermined value.

When using the algorithm, can we separate the calls to $f(x)$ and $f(x)=a$? 
That is, instead of querying $F(x) \equiv (f(x) = a)$ around $2^{n/2}$ times (interleaved with amplification), is it possible to query $f(x)$ once at the begining and then repeat $2^{n/2}$ times $f(x)=a$ (interleaved with amplification) ?

Comment: It feels like you'd be applying the diffusion operator to an $(n+m)$-qubit input rather than merely an $n$-qubit input?  You might need $2^{(n+m)/2}$ such repetitions?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't see why. The diffusion is applied to the input $n$ bits (just like in the database search).

Comment: It seems like you want to create a composite function, first $f(x)$ and then $F(x)$.  Initially you'll create a superposition $\vert x\rangle\vert 000\cdots\rangle\vert 0\rangle$, then $\vert x\rangle\vert f(x)\rangle\vert 0\rangle$, and then $\vert x \rangle\vert f(x)\rangle\vert F(x)\rangle$.  How would you rotate?  Conditioned on $F(x)=1$?

Comment: Yes, conditioned on $F(x)=1$. Also, keep in mind that $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$ is entangled.

Comment: But if you diffuse just on $\vert x\rangle$, $\vert f(x)\rangle$ gets in the way to stop the interference from the diffusion operator?

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a state given to you as $\vert x\rangle\vert f(x)\rangle$, and you wish to only conditionally rotate when $f(x)=a$, diffuse over $x$, conditionally rotate when $f(x)=a$, diffuse over $x$, ... conditionally rotate when $f(x)=a$, diffuse over $x$, and measure.

If I understand your question, then I think the issue is in the "diffuse over $x$."

Because you can't simply diffuse over the mixed state $\vert x\rangle$, but you must diffuse over the pure state $\vert x\rangle\vert f(x)\rangle$.

If $\vert f(x)\rangle$ has not been [uncomputed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomputation) back to $\vert 0\rangle$, then the diffusion will not lead to constructive/destructive interference in the first register.  Even if you are diffusing only over the first register $\vert x\rangle$, the second register $\vert f(x)\rangle$ gets in the way.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide reference for "you can't simply diffuse over the mixed state".